# Login screen in Django - Subclassing or creating a form template?

Tags: django

Previously I have been investigating several solutions how to register with email address instead of username. All the sources I found focus on creating a custom backend and rolling the Signup page. While this works for me, I couldn't find a single solution that explains what to do with the login screen.

> **First of all my approach with Email authorization**
>
> Registration: I take the email address and create a hash of it as the username and store it.
>
> Login:  I take the email address again and create a hash of it and try
>   to find a username with the same hash.

**How its done in code:**

In the **settings**:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('MyApp.auth_backends.CustomUserModelBackend',)
CUSTOM_USER_MODEL = 'MyApp.CustomUser'
```

In **models.py**

```
class CustomUser(User):
    timezone = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Europe/London')
    objects = UserManager()
```

I have customized the registration like this:

**View.py**

```
def register_page(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = CustomUser.objects.create_user(
                username=md5(form.cleaned_data['email']).digest().encode('base64')[:-1],
                password=form.cleaned_data['password2'],
                email=form.cleaned_data['email']
            )   

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/register/success/')
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
    variables = RequestContext(request, {'form':form})
    return render_to_response('registration/register.html', variables)
```

in **auth_backends.CustomUserModelBackend:**

calculate the hash of the given email address to find the related username.

```
class CustomUserModelBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        try:
            # The parameter Username is here really just the email address, I get 
            # the hash for the email parameter and try to find the user.

            hash_user = md5(username).digest().encode('base64')[:-1],
            user = self.user_class.objects.get(username=hash_user)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except self.user_class.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return self.user_class.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except self.user_class.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    @property
    def user_class(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_user_class'):
            self._user_class = get_model(*settings.CUSTOM_USER_MODEL.split('.', 2))
            if not self._user_class:
                raise ImproperlyConfigured('Could not get custom user model')
        return self._user_class
```

**Now I am stuck with login screen.**

I have done it like this, but I get redirected back to login screen without getting any error shown.

**url.py**

```
(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
```

**registration/login.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}user login{% endblock %}
{% block head %}User login{% endblock %}
{% block content %}{% if form.errors %}
    <p>Your email and password didn't match</p>
{% endif %}
    <form action="." method="post">
        <p>
            <label for="id_username">Email:</label>{{ form.username }}
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="id_password">Password:</label>{{ form.password }}
        </p>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="/" />
        <input type="submit" value="login" />
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

I know the solution is already problematic since I need an email input for "username" and not a charfield.

1) What do I have to do to override the field type?

2) I still can't login, it says username doesn't match password.

I debugged it in Authenticate and it doesnt find the user

```
            hash_user = md5(username).digest().encode('base64')[:-1],
            user = self.user_class.objects.get(username=hash_user)
```

Isn't the hash of the same email address always the same? What could I be missing?

**Update:**

I can see clearly the hash code is saved as username in the database and I can see how within the Authenticate `user = self.user_class.objects.get(username=hash_user)` the hashcode is the same value as in the database.   However it still doesn't retrieve the user. Why?

[image]
[image]

**UPDATE 2:**

I found the problem.  I had one comma there by mistake and that turned the hash into a tuple. Oh dear

This is correct and works:

```
hash_user = md5(username).digest().encode('base64')[:-1]
user = self.user_class.objects.get(username=hash_user)
```

We have now the full solution here. Just one thing.

Is anyone able to help me with 1) ?  How can I override the username charfield please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, [this is not currently possible](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#field-name-hiding-is-not-permitted).

Comment: Ahh I see. Thanks Chris. Would you say it is a good idea to mirror django.contrib.auth.forms.AuthenticationForm but use an email field instead of a CharField?

Comment: With "mirror" I mean like copy and paste as a new form. :)

Comment: I've definitely found myself copying, pasting, and editing django source code in instances where I can't just override it to my tastes. For example, certain methods on class based views where I want the exact same behavior, minus a line.

Comment: I see. Thanks Chris. I have copied authorizationForm, which worked fine. Then I had to create my own view to make use of the new form. Hence I copied the Login() view from original as well and made sure it instantiates the new customForm within. However there is one other method it relies on: auth_login(request, form.get_user()) which comes from auth/__init__.py I also had to copy that one over to my views. It works!!! But its just that there is a lot of sensitive Session handling going on there. It feels scary, what if I would break something in the session management with that. :) Hack..

Comment: Rather than copying the `login()` view, wherever you use it just pass in your new form. If you look at [the source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L27), it accepts a custom form. So in your urls.py, add that in to the urlpattern calling your login view: `url(r'^login/$', login, {'authentication_form':myCustomAuthenticationForm}, name='login'),`. That should keep you from needing to duplicate all that secure code.

Comment: WoW this is the perfect solution. So clean. Thank you so much Chris :) I solved it like this: (r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'authentication_form':CustomAuthenticationForm}),